# about AVFoundation: why my app just worked on first time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, jailbreak

im  testing a simple code. it used AVFoundation. when i run it. it can take a picture and save it to the album. but when i run it twice, it not worked. i rebuild it and worked again. but just one time.
can somebody tell me why?(I'm sorry. I'm not good at english....><)

```
//
//  main.m
//  test
//
//  Created by John Suu on 1/22/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 John Suu. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h"

AVCaptureSession *session;
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput;
AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;

void settings(){

    NSError *error = nil;

    // 入力と出力からキャプチャーセッションを作成
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // 正面に配置されているカメラを取得
    AVCaptureDevice *camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // カメラからの入力を作成し、セッションに追加
    videoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:camera error:&error];
    [session addInput:videoInput];

    // 画像への出力を作成し、セッションに追加
    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    // キャプチャーセッションから入力のプレビュー表示を作成

    // セッション開始
    [session startRunning];
}

void takePicture(){

    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [stillImageOutput    connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    /*if (videoConnection == nil) {
        return;
    }*/

    // ビデオ入力から画像を非同期で取得。ブロックで定義されている処理が呼び出され、画像データを引数から取得する
    [stillImageOutput
     captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
     completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
         if (imageDataSampleBuffer == NULL) {
             return;
         }

         // 入力された画像データからJPEGフォーマットとしてデータを取得
         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput   jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

         // JPEGデータからUIImageを作成
         //[imageData writeToFile:@"/var/mobile" atomically:NO];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

         // アルバムに画像を保存


         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);


     }];


}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    settings();
    takePicture();
   // NSTimer *timer =
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:nil selector:nil userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    NSLog(@"runing.it works!\n");


    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your app support backgrounding? Looking at your code, this may be the reason.

When you quit your app by default it will move in background mode. When you launch it again it will move from background to foreground. Your `main` function will not be called again as in background mode app is just suspended. This means that `takePicture` function will be called only once when you launch your app from scratch. Try closing your app (double click home) before launching it again.

To solve this just move the code that takes picture into `AppDelegate` methods. If you don't know, which ones, read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

Comment: and i have another question. i build the app and run it form terminal command ./test(the app's binary file), it printf out message. but don't take any photo. i don't know why. i have write a location app. just launched the same way. it works. should i add something in my info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

Try addingAdd a function which stops the AVCaptureSession before opening the app again.

```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {

        settings();
        takePicture();
        stopSession();
       // NSTimer *timer =
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:nil selector:nil userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        NSLog(@"runing.it works!\n");


        @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
      }

    }


void stopSession() { 
        [session stopRunning];
}
```

Issue is because you are trying to start a session which is already running. Few other checks might be required as well like whether the session is started, already running etc. Throw few flags to check those and try!

Comment: i added stopSession() to my main function. now, it totally can not work.i launched the app, just like nothing happened.

Comment: and i have another question. i build the app and run it form terminal command ./test(the app's binary file), it printf out message. but don't take any photo. i don't know why. i have write a location app. just launched the same way. it works. should i add something in my info.plist?